# having trouble with a "\n" and scanf

Tags: c, newline, printf, scanf

Here is the code

```
       printf("\n");
       printf("Enter a integer vaule:");
       scanf("%d" , &num3);
       printf("You entered: %015d", num3);


       printf("Enter a float value:");
       scanf("%f", &deci3);
       printf("You entered: %15.2f", deci3);
       printf("\n");
```

the output is

```
       Enter a integer vaule:4.4
       You entered: 000000000000004
       Enter a float value:You entered:            0.40
```

The problem is this code is not stopping at

```
       printf("Enter a float value:");
```

and this scanf

```
      scanf("%f", &deci3);
```

seems to be getting its value from the previous scanf

Comment: If you want a decent line input function, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921 - it's ideal for line based input which you can then `sscanf` and check for formatting problems as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%d` conversion stops wherever the integer stops, which is a decimal point. If you want to discard the input there, do so explicitly… `getc` in a loop, `fgets`, or such. This also allows you to validate the input. The program should probably complain about `4.4`.

Comment: I think the `scanf` always clean the return. he get this output, since he used getc before scanf.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it dont complains if you type 4.4 for the int

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char buffer[256];
int i;
float f;

printf("enter an integer : ");
fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &i);
printf("you entered : %d\n", i);

printf("enter a float : ");
fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f);
printf("you entered : %f\n", f) ;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: getting "warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
"

Comment: `gets` is just begging for a buffer overflow. You should use `fgets`, which allows you to limit how much is read.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function works this way per the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html):

> An input item shall be defined as the longest sequence of input bytes (up to any specified maximum field width, which may be measured in characters or bytes dependent on the conversion specifier) which is **an initial subsequence of a matching sequence.** [Emphasis added.]

In your example, the following C string represents the contents of *stdin* when the first `scanf` call requests input: `"4.4\n"`.

For this initial call, your format string consists of a single specifier, `%d`, which represents an integer. That means that the function will read as many bytes as possible from *stdin* which satisfy the definition of an integer. In your example, that's just `4`, leaving *stdin* to contain `".4\n"` (if this is confusing for you, you might want to check out [what an integer is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)).

The second call to `scanf` does not request any additional input from the user because *stdin* already contains `".4\n"` as shown above. Using the format string `%f` attempts to read a floating-point number from the current value of *stdin*. The number it reads is `.4` (per the specification, `scanf` disregards whitespace like `\n` in most cases).

To fully answer your question, the problem is not that you're misusing `scanf`, but rather that there's a mismatch between what you're inputting and how you're expecting `scanf` to behave.

If you want to guarantee that people can't mess up the input like that, I would recommend using `strtol` and `strtod` in conjunction with `fgets` instead.

Answer (score -2):

use a  `fflush(stdin)` function after the fist `scanf()`, this will flush the input buffer.